# ASP.NET, use data-toggle attribute in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, attributes

I'm using Bootstrap which has a tabbed menu. It uses the attribute data-toggle="tab" to open the tabs. Right now I have a button within one of the tabs, and when I click the button it runs some C# code from the code behind file. It uses DataBind(), so the page will reload. However, when it reloads it obviously has the default tab open, but I want it to reload with a different tab open. Is there a way I can run the data-toggle from within my C# code?

The HTML tabs look like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li runat="server" id="tabHome" class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
  <li runat="server" id="tabUsers"><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Users</a></li>
  <li runat="server" id="tabRoles"><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> Roles</a></li>
  <li runat="server" id="tabGames"><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Games</a></li>
</ul>
```

And within the tab "tabRoles" i have a button that executes some code:

```
 if (!Roles.RoleExists(txtRolename.Text))
        {
            Roles.CreateRole(txtRolename.Text);
            BindUsers();
            BindRoles();
            feedback.Visible = true;
            lblFeedback.Text = "<strong>Success!</strong> The role "+txtRolename.Text+" was created.";
            txtRolename.Text = "";

        }

        else
        {
          //Role already exists blabla
        }
```

Comment: i don't think that's possible as bootstrap is a browser framework. Your program needs to handle postback scenarios. May be using jquery & hiddenfield server control.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're marking each list item as a "server control" via the id and runat attributes, you can read these objects in your server side code.  Try using the "attributes" collection property of the LI item's to get each tab's data-toggle value, css classes, etc.

From there, you can use those values to tie in with your client side code and activate the appropriate tab on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Your List items have the runat=server on them, so you can use those in your code behind.

Something like this:

```
if (!Roles.RoleExists(txtRolename.Text))
{
    //Roles stuff

    //figure out which tab you want to return to
    tabUsers.CssClass = "active";
    tabHome.Attributes.Remove("class");
    //do the same for other tabs
}
```

You could also set some hidden variables and add logic directly to your html to show/hide tabs.